# How do I preserve the Font/Color of a Swift document generated via Xcode in a custom iOS/MacOS Application?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, document

**Scenario:** a rudimentary iOS/MacOS application generated by Xcode 'document' template with the ability to read/write .swift file.

**Purpose:** to have a Swift-Language source-code viewer for both Mac & iOS for purview only.

I merely would like to have a simple iOS Application that I can use to store Swift code snippets for study on-the-go (mobile).

I'm able to view .swift files but I lost the font/colors used to display within Xcode.

**Question:** how do I view the original font/color text? ...or 
Must I have to convert the entire source-code into an AttributedText?

**Example:** I want to preserve the code as is shown below:

[image]

Comment: Depends on how accurate of a highlighting you need. For the "ground truth", you would need to use [SourceKit](https://github.com/apple/sourcekit-lsp), which parses Swift code in the same way as the compiler, so it guarantees the most accurate parsing. Might be pretty hard to set that up in an iOS environment, though.

Comment: My purpose is to have a cache of Swift snippets that I can study within an iPhone.   It only needs to be read only (i.e., a 'reference manual'), sourced from MacOS.  It could be stored on the iCloud and probably have a local copy when not connected to any WiFi.

However, I'll study SourceKit and go from there.  Thanks.

Comment: I think your easiest bet is to just commit them to a git repository and view them on GitHub, GitLab, etc.

Comment: I already am using both GitHub and BitBucket for entire projects.    I've toyed with Apple's iOS Pages and that works great for everything.  I converted .swift to an RTF and that works okay using Pages with Cloud.  So can create the docs via Mac and read them via iPhone via iCloud.   So perhaps a cache of RTF/Folder is a way to go.  I was using Dash™ for both Mac & iOS; but they drop support for iOS.  Hence the alternative route.  No need to over-engineer this stuff.

Comment: I'm looking at Quiver™; I had used that years ago.  I'll see if they improved it.